# Problems updating Listview from Saved contact in database android

Tags: android

Good day all, please been having this trouble and i can't seem to see why. Basically what am trying to do is pick a contact via the contact api, save in database, and then display in a listview. but for some reason, after i get the contacts details, my custom adapter is not called anymore, its only called on when the activity is first created, and hence empty. Please what could i have missed. Thank you.

heres my code:

```
public class GroupDetails extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

//variable for debugging the application

public static final String TAG = "MyApp.Debug";

    //request code for using with action pick intent
    static final int PICK_CONTACT = 1;

    //initial variables
    Button add_button;
    TextView label;
    ListView list;
    ResponderDB dbadapter;
    DueCustomCursorAdapter cursoradapter;
    //DueCustomCursorLoader loader;

    //cursor to retrieve contact details 
    private Cursor contactsCursor;


    String groupname;
    long rowId;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.group_detail_list);

 //only intialize here. database will be open in custom cursor loader

dbadapter = new ResponderDB(this); 

        getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
        /*Read intent and the extras passed*/
           Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

            if(!extra.isEmpty() || extra.equals(null)){
             groupname = extra.getString("group_name");
             rowId = extra.getLong("rowId");
            }

        list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        add_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.add_button_id);
        label = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.group_label_id);


        Log.d(TAG, "calling custom adapter here now");
        cursoradapter = new DueCustomCursorAdapter(GroupDetails.this, null, CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER );
        list.setAdapter(cursoradapter);

        add_button.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int selection = view.getId();
        if(selection == R.id.add_button_id){

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        if(requestCode == PICK_CONTACT){
            getContactInfo(data);
        }
    }


    private void getContactInfo(Intent intent) {

        String number = null; 
        String name = null; 

        String[] projection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, 
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

        CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(this,intent.getData(),
                null,null,null,null);

        contactsCursor = loader.loadInBackground();
        if(contactsCursor.moveToFirst()){

        String id = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
        name = contactsCursor.getString(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        //get the Phone Number
        Cursor numberCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI
                , null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] {id}, null);
        while(numberCursor.moveToNext()){
            number = numberCursor.getString(numberCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        }

        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Successfully added contacts for group");
        //dbadapter.updateGroup(rowId, values);

        dbadapter.saveContacts(name, number, String.valueOf(rowId));
        cursoradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).onContentChanged();
    }


    public static final class DueCustomCursorLoader extends SimpleCursorLoader {
        public static final String TAG = "MyApp.Debug";
        public static int RETRIEVE_CODE = 1;

        ResponderDB dbadapter1;
        int retrieveCode;


        public DueCustomCursorLoader(Context context, ResponderDB dbadapter) {
            super(context);
           this.dbadapter1= dbadapter;

        }

        public DueCustomCursorLoader(Context context, ResponderDB dbadapter, int retrieveCode){

            super(context);
            this.dbadapter1 = dbadapter;
            this.retrieveCode = retrieveCode;
        }



        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor cursor = null;

            dbadapter1.open();

                cursor = dbadapter1.readContact(retrieveCode);

            return cursor;
        }

    }

    public class DueCustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        public static final String TAG = "SmsResponder.Debug";
        private Context myContext;



        public DueCustomCursorAdapter(Context context,Cursor c, int flags) {
            super(context, c, flags);
            myContext = context;

        }

        //never seem to get here 
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            String contactName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ResponderDB.NAME));
            String contactNumber = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ResponderDB.NUMBER));

            Log.d(TAG, "contact name is " + contactName);
            Log.d(TAG, "contact number is " + contactNumber);

            holder.contact_name.setText(contactName);
            holder.contact_number.setText(contactNumber);
        }

        @Override   
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(myContext).inflate(R.layout.group_detail_item, parent,false);
                holder.contact_name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.group_item_id);
                holder.contact_number = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.group_subitem_id);
                view.setTag(holder);

                return view;     
        }

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
          TextView text;
          TextView contact_name;
          TextView contact_number;
          CheckBox checkbox;
        }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle arg1) {

        return new DueCustomCursorLoader(GroupDetails.this, dbadapter, (int)rowId);
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        cursoradapter.swapCursor(data);

    }


    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> arg0) {

        cursoradapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

}
```

Am not getting any issue from the database, so code not added here.

Comment: anyone with an idea? or seen anything a bit odd. am really confused about this.

Comment: are You getting any contacts under if(contactsCursor.moveToFirst()){ ? Probably, after saving contact to the database You need to restartLoader() to get yours database requery and let 
onLoadFinished to be called again to allow adapter work with new data,

Comment: @sandrstar, yes i am. will give it a try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: @sandrstar, but isn't this  getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).onContentChanged(); supposed to requery the database?

Comment: probably, but 1) I think it's the right way to call some on* method which looks like callback; 2) Recently faced number of tricky issues with CursorLoader whose causes it not to be loaded, so it might be good to give a try to another restart way;

Comment: @sandrstar thanks it worked! sorry to bother, but while i was testing the code, i kept saving contacts into the database anytime i ran my code. with the changes you suggested, it now displays all the contacts i had previously added to the database. my question now is, any reason why did the loader not pick them up in onCreate() method?, only as i restarted it like you said, that it did. by the way i also have a previous activity on the stack that roughly has the same implementation as this activity, so i don't know if that be the reason. any thoughts? thanks once again

Comment: not sure, but it might be related to calling initLoader in onCreate(). Based on my experience (also, did some research on loaders sources to confirm it) it's better to 1) avoid initLoader() calls at all and use just resetLoader(); 2) Don't call reset/init from onCreate(), because you might not get callback about completion (not sure, but as I remember it won't be delivered to not started fragments/activities); All these advices are for support library (up to 8 version, haven't checked 9 yet).

Comment: @sandrstar noted! thanks for the information. would do some research on what you have just said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After saving contact to the database You need to restartLoader() to get yours database requery and let onLoadFinished to be called again to allow adapter work with new data.

Answer (score 0):

I would try reversing these two lines (it looks to me like your telling the list to update itself before you update the cursor):

```
   cursoradapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
   getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).onContentChanged();
```

To this:

```
   getSupportLoaderManager().getLoader(0).onContentChanged();
   cursoradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```